# How do I launch The Littlest JupyterHub as admin?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub

I'm trying to get up to speed with The Littlest JupyterHub.

I've followed the documentation and added myself as an admin with the following.
[image]

Updated my config file with my key and cert then launched the hub with `jupyterhub -f ./jupyterhub_config.py`.

I then get to this screen:
[image]

My issue is that I dont see the control panel described here:
[image]

Can anyone suggest where I've gone wrong?

Comment: Were you seeing the admin dashboard when logging in before you complicated things? In otherwords wth one admin server and no certs and SSL stuff?  Also the restarting command after updating the configuration is supposed to be `sudo tljh-config reload`, see [here](https://tljh.jupyter.org/en/latest/topic/tljh-config.html?highlight=jupyterhub#reloading-jupyterhub-to-apply-configuration). Plus, I don't understand why you are connecting to it on localhost? You connection strategy doesn't look like anything I see in the documentation.

Comment: No I've never seen the admin dashboard, the documentation said to access the dashboard/JupyterHub notebook through my servers IP address but this times out hence accessing through local host as suggesting here - https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/issues/2364. Could you refer me to the connection strategy outlined in documentation? I do have certs and SSL configured and set in the configs with one admin but no luck.

Comment: As for the connections strategies, you can go to [Installing](https://tljh.jupyter.org/en/latest/install/index.html) and look in the individual guides. The specific step is usually towards the end of 'Step #1' of those guides, usually one or two steps before the 'Sign in' image of the JupyterHub login page.

Comment: Is [the example you pointed at in issues](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/issues/2364) for the littlest Jupyter Hub? I have only used localhost with things running directly on my machine or when I am using a SSH tunnel  to connect & to forward via a port Jupyter (not JupyterHub) from a remote headless machine. Maybe that's what you are doing, but it doesn't correspond to anything how the examples for The Littlest JupyterHub are run. Doesn't mean what you are doing isn't valid. Just makes me question it given you aren't seeing the normal stuff.